# Ubuntu freezes when i move the audio volume slider

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, freeze

I own a gaming laptop and I am using **Ubuntu LTS** version.
I am experiencing this weird issue where ubuntu freezes if I move the audio volume slider, it kinda **lags** and sometimes **freezes**.
This happened on **Spotify** as well as **Rhythmbox**.

Initially I thought this is because of Nvidia not being fully supported by linux so I uninstalled all nvidia drivers.

for the command `lspci | grep -i audio`
The output is:

> 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
> 05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
> 05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
> 05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller

I also have  ***WhiteSur-gtk-theme*** installed if this information helps.

Specs of my laptop:

> ASUS TUF Gaming A15, 15.6-inch (39.62 cms) FHD 144Hz, AMD Ryzen 5 4600H, 4GB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, Gaming Laptop (8GB/512GB SSD

**Firefox** lags sometimes as well.
Please help me solve this issue as I am not able to normally use my laptop at all despite my laptop being so powerful.

Some fixes I tried but didn't work:

1. switched to flatpak from snap
2. Uninstalled Nvidia drivers